# How can we alter a single pin of ATxMEGA128?

Tags: atmega, programming, output, io

this might be a basic question but I did try searching for the answer before posting the question.

So, I am trying to set one of the ports to output. I used

```
PORTC.DIRSET = 0xFF; //Set Port C to output
```

Now, I have connected the enable pin of my sensor to say Pin 1. How do I turn it on? As in how to I access a particular pin of port C to turn it high?

Also How can i make it go low?

(I am using a force sensitive resistor and want the sensor to start working only when an input is received from the force sensitive resistor circuit)

Comment: The term you're looking for is bit masking.

Comment: i guess i figure it out myself! PORTC.OUT = (1<<1)

Answer (score 2):

The ATxmega has special function registers to make setting and clearing pins very easy:

```
#define PIN_NUM             4            // mask for the specific pin (in this case 
#define PIN_MASK        (1 << PIN_NUM)   // pin 4) in the PORT


if(FSR_output1)                              //If output from FSR circuit
{
    PORTC.OUTSET = PIN_MASK;               //SET sensor enable high
}
else
{
    PORTC.OUTCLR = PIN_MASK;              //SET sensor enable low
}
```

These registers make it so you don't need to deal with read-modify-write cycles for the IO lines. The IO port state is automatically ORed with whatever is written to `OUTSET`, and a write to `OUTCLR` is inverted, and ANDed with the inverted value. As such, you can do single-instruction operations to control pin state. It's a very nice tool, and one of the nice things about the xmega parts.

[image]

Note that there are also the complementary `PORTx.DIRSET` and `PORTx.DIRCLR` resisters, as well as `PORTx.OUTTGL`/`PORTx.DIRTGL`, which toggles the pins that correspond to each binary 1 written to the register.

Comment: +1 I *love* this feature. It compensates for gcc's inability to use bit-manipulation instructions

Comment: These also have the added advantage of being atomic operations.  No read modify write, so no worrying about an interrupt handler changing a different bit in the middle of the masking operation.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself!

```
PORTC.DIRSET = 0xFF;                           //SET PORT C to output
uint8_t sample2 = PORTC.IN;                   //Naming the port
uint8_t sensor_enable = (sample2 >> 6) & 1;  //Naming an individual Pin

if(FSR_output1)                              //If output from FSR circuit
{
    sensor_enable = 1;               //SET sensor enable high
}
else
{
    sensor_enable = 0;              //SET sensor enable low
}
```